# Unverified breakpoint in Visual Studio Code with Chrome Debugger

Tags: angularjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've looked at the many answers already posted, and I still can't find a solution.

I'm working on a legacy AngularJS application that has been partially converted to Typescript.  The sources are in `C:\Users\myname\dev\project\client\src`. This is my `launch.json` entry:

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Chrome",
    "port": 9222,
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/#/home",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client/src",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///*": "${webRoot}/*"
    },
    "trace": true

}
```

When I try to set a breakpoint in VS Code, it says "Unverified breakpoint". A typical log in the trace file for this action looks like this:

```
[13:43:13.020 UTC] From client: setBreakpoints({"source":{"name":"some-page.controller.ts","path":"C:\\Users\\username\\dev\\project\\client\\src\\some-subfolder\\some-page.controller.ts"},"lines":[77],"breakpoints":[{"line":77}],"sourceModified":false})
[13:43:13.020 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"setBreakpointsRequest","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.45","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.11.3","Versions.Target.CRDPVersion":"1.3","Versions.Target.Revision":"@518a41c1fa7ce1c8bb5e22346e82e42b4d76a96f","Versions.Target.UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36","Versions.Target.V8":"7.4.288.26","Versions.Target.Project":"Chrome","Versions.Target.Version":"74.0.3729.131","fileExt":".ts"}}}
[13:43:13.020 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":34,"command":"setBreakpoints","success":true,"body":{"breakpoints":[{"verified":false,"line":77,"message":"Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?).","id":1006}]}}
```

Chrome DevTools is able to find the source map at `webpack://client/src/some-subfolder\\some-page.controller.ts` and it correctly sets a breakpoint. When this breakpoint is hit, VS Code loads a file that it identifies as `C:\Users\username\dev\project\client\src\client\src\some-subfolder\some-page.controller.ts`. The `\client\src` part of the path is duplicated, but this location does not exist.

If I then set a breakpoint in VS Code in the file with the invalid path, it works, and the application breaks when it hits it. Of course I'm unable to do this for any other file because the path where VS Code thinks it has found it doesn't exist.

I've tried various combinations of `webRoot` and `sourceMapPathOverrides` without success and I've made sure that VS Code is started in the project folder. Can anyone suggest a solution?

**Edit**
I've also tried removing the `sourceMapPathOverrides` entry with no success. When I hit a breakpoint set in DevTools, VS Code identifies the file as `1521`, which is listed under Loaded Scripts in `webpack-internal`.  But when I open any of these numbered scripts in VS Code (rather than by hitting a breakpoint), I see the generated Javascript, rather than the mapped Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  It works correctly with the following (much simpler) configuration:

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/",
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///*": "${webRoot}/*"
}
```